# Jquery UI Framework Icons

Tags: jquery-ui

On the [Themeroller page](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/), the author of jQuery UI shows that there are icons available if you use certain keywords.  Example:

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-circle-close">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close">
</span>
</li>
```

This creates a nice little X in the middle of a circle, framed by a box with rounded corners and a border.

But what if my icons are not in a list?  What if they're in a table cell for instance?

```
<td>
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-circle-close">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
</li>
</td>
```

This works, although it's not technically correct, because I don't have an opening and closing < ul> element.

Do I use

```
<td class="showcities">
<span class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-circle-close">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s">
</span>
</span>
</td>
```

If so, what should the css be to define the ui-corner-all the same as the Themeroller example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of span, use `<div>` here, like this

```
<td class="showcities">
  <div class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-circle-close">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks Nick!  They're a little bit wider than the example page, but I think I might be able to style them.